# Calculate the area of ​the domain D bounded by the loop of the curve

Tags: integration, area

$\left ( x+y \right )^{5}= x^{2}y^{2}$ I can try to do it, but I have a problem with polar system, I don`t know how to build this graphic and calculate the integral.

Comment: Please try to do it.  If you get stuck, explain where you get stuck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(r \sin t+r \cos t)^5-r^4 \sin ^2 t \cos ^2t=0$

Collect $r$ in the parenthesis and take it out

$r^5(\sin t+\cos t)^5=r^4 \sin^2 t \cos^2 t$

simplify $r^4$

$r(\sin t+\cos t)^5= \sin^2 t \cos^2 t$

The curve has polar equation
$$r = \frac{\sin ^2 t\cos ^2 t}{(\sin t +\cos t)^5};\;t\in[0,2\pi]$$
but to get the loop you have to consider the interval $t\in[0,\pi/2]$

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \left(\frac{\sin ^2 t\cos ^2 t}{(\sin t +\cos t)^5}\right)^2\,dt$$

$$A=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^{\pi/2} \frac{\sin ^4 t\cos ^4 t}{(\sin t +\cos t)^{10}}\,dt$$

$$
...
$$

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but I dont know how to build the formula to calculate the area